# UISearchController not Shown

Tags: swift3, uisearchcontroller

I am learning `UISearchController` by following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) tutorial. However, the `UISearchBar` is not shown. This is my code:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Candies"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

And this is how my app looks like:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you scroll down the table view the search bar will appear but you can set the hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling property to false so the search bar remains, as the documentation says, regardless of the current scroll position.

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```